# Download and open an zip file ingame on unity for android

Tags: android, unity, fbx

I would like to know if it is possible to have a game that would download a rar or zip file from a website and extract it to the internal storage for use, and if it is a good option since i have to use a directory structure to open fbx models that have the texture on a folder with the same name of the fbx.

The App is made for android and the files should not be bigger than 30mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `System.IO.Compression` (there are more options out there, just google) and use whatever folder structure you want under the path defined by `Application.persistentDataPath`.

Normally with *Unity Pro* we use [Asset Bundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html) to deal with remote assets, but what you ask is perfectly feasible.

Between both, it really depends on what you want to do, and which type of files you want to manage. If they are Unity asset files, I'd say to go with the Asset Bundles.

Comment: Thanks i will have to use zip files since the end user won't be able to use unity to make assets bundle.